# Where does --be_ip argument come from a command: nohup nodejs server.js?

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, nohup

I'm now learning how to deploy my node.js app to Google Compute Engine, and reading a tutorial on Google Cloud Platform, which deploys node.js app with MongoDB to Google Compute Engine.

The tutorial guides you through a step by step, which consists of the following:

1. Launch a backend instance and make it open to HTTP port
2. Install MongoDB on backend
3. Launch a frontend instance and make it open to HTTP port
4. Install nodejs on frontend and clone node.js app there, and launch a server

However, the last command on the tutorial is the following:

> nohup nodejs server.js nohup nodejs server.js --be_ip XXX --fe_ip YYY &

But I don't get where the `--be_ip` and `--fe__ip` come from. The parameter of the arguments is a backend and frontend internal IP, so I can easily guess what the name means.

However, both `man nodejs` and `man nohup` doesn't show these arguments. Also, when I tried googling by a keyword "`--be_ip --fe_ip command`", [the resultant page shows the google tutorial-related pages specifically](https://www.google.com/#q=--be_ip+--fe_ip+command).

So I wonder where these arguments come from. How can I be informed more about these arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a set of optional arguments that you can set to whatever you like. Those arguments shall be used in a program, for example via `process.argv.` or `optimist` library.

That's why when you googled it the resultant pages are only those tied to its relevant results, and `man nohup` or `man nodejs` didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 arguments are for `server.js`. That explains `man nodejs` and `man nohup` did  help. You can find them in `server.js`.